# How to automatically open a website and fill out a form and submit it?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, automation

Everyday I have to login for work and I wanted to know how can I automate the process without installing a 3rd party software or browser extension since I'm using my work's computer.

I created a batch file to open the login website.

```
@ECHO OFF
start https://login.example.com
```

And I know that if I run this code on the developer console it would achieve what I'm looking for.

```
document.getElementById("username").value = 'UserExample';
document.getElementById("passwd").value = 'PassExample';
document.getElementById("Log_On").click();
```

But I can't find how to automate the second part which is filling out the form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need use a webdriving library.
you can use selenum. its easy and cross language (python , js , java , c# , ruby and kotlin)

selenum documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

if you dont want install any softwhere you can use c# if dotnet installed on your computer as default or use python PyInstaller (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to compile python to an executable file (you dont need install output file.this just run).